# Is it possible to use PostgreSQL with Google AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

The documentation mentions that MySQL can be used:

> Your app can access tens of gigabytes of data stored in Google Cloud
>   SQL, a **MySQL** relational database hosted on Google Cloud Platform.

However, it seems to be have been written before PostgreSQL was available on Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for PostgreSQL is not available. See https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql, it says:

> Note: App Maker supports only MySQL databases. You can't use
>   PostgreSQL.